# Trying to replicate Matlab regress function in Python

Tags: matlab, scipy

I am having some difficulty to replciate Matlab's `regress` function output using scipy `linregress` function.

Here is the data

```
pupVals = [3.40621246270059, 3.39361245626222, 3.37960434985898, 3.36422005129091, 3.34750704680340, 3.32952815194744,
               3.31035997313977, 3.29009299139087, 3.26883227275573, 3.24668690892347, 3.22376158035874, 3.20015774115851,
               3.17597533905954, 3.15130446393993, 3.12622016870185, 3.10078008972008, 3.07503065688319, 3.04901239477419,
               3.02276360223545, 2.99632186567962, 2.96972062051014]
    
defVals = [ -0.676069340690958, -0.681299901070580, -0.687103823182625, -0.693490568594932, -0.700466450335011,
                      -0.708027898057120, -0.716167334731881, -0.724878961238070, -0.734138903033690, -0.743919748266449,
                      -0.754183596434113, -0.764899153546520, -0.776036371746185, -0.787551515041980, -0.799395767551789,
                      -0.811524533752894, -0.823893965641479, -0.836469554360099, -0.849231693452297, -0.862141390106238,
                      -0.875133488454364]

res = linregress(pupVals, defVals)
```

the matlab output looks like below
in matlab I make `defvals` as a 21x2 matrix with ones in first column as suggested in matlab regress help documentation

```
[SlopeFit,CIS] = regress(pupvals, defvals)

SlopeFit =

    4.8830
    2.1939

CIS =

    4.8604    4.9056
    2.1644    2.2234
```

and I use SlopeFit(2) and CIS(2,1), CIS(2,2)

Any suggestions on how to replicate the results?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
res = linregress(pupVals, defVals)
SlopeFit = np.array([res.intercept, res.slope])
errs = np.array([res.stderr,intercept_stderr])
CIS = SlopeFit[:,None] + 1.96*errs[:,None]*np.array([[1,-1]])
```